# How can I display a dialog whenever my stream gets a new value?

Tags: flutter, dart, stream

I have the following bloc provider

```
class CloudMessagingBloc{
  StreamController<NotificationModel> _streamController = StreamController<NotificationModel>();
  Stream<NotificationModel> get stream => _streamController.stream;
  final FirebaseMessaging _firebaseMessaging = FirebaseMessaging();

  CloudMessagingBloc() {
    if (Platform.isIOS) _firebaseMessaging.requestNotificationPermissions(IosNotificationSettings());
    _firebaseMessaging.configure(
      onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        _streamController.add(NotificationModel.fromMap(message));
      },
      onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        _streamController.add(NotificationModel.fromMap(message));
      },
      onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        _streamController.add(NotificationModel.fromMap(message));
      },
    );
  }

  void dispose(){
    _streamController.close();
  }
}
```

And implement it like this

```
  static Widget create() {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        Provider(create: (_) => DelayBloc(seconds: 2)),
        Provider(
          create: (_) => CloudMessagingBloc(),
          dispose: (BuildContext context, CloudMessagingBloc bloc) => bloc.dispose(),
          lazy: false,
        ),
      ],
      child: TheRootPage(),
    );
  }
```

In my root page stateless widget. But now I have a problem, because I want to show a dialog once whenever the stream emits a new value. So I impemented a streambuilder for this and the notification shows correctly when a new value get's added

```
StreamBuilder(
  stream: cloudMessagingBloc.stream,
  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<NotificationModel> snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.active && snapshot.hasData)
      SchedulerBinding.instance
          .addPostFrameCallback((_) => _showNotificationDialog(context, snapshot.data));
```

But the problem is whenever the widget rebuilds that holds this streambuilder, the notification get's shown again because the condition is met, which is not something I want, because I only want to show a notification once. So how do I prevent this from happening? It feels like I have a structural problem, and I just can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see 3 possible solutions:

1. You need to use https://pub.dev/packages/equatable to check is it new state or not. This is also from ferangel(author of BLOC package). You can find examples with equitable and Bloc in google.
2. You can create a global key and then use it to show dialogs(if you have the global key, you can retrieve context from it and than call dialogService.showMyDialog() from bloc).
3. You can use for example https://pub.dev/packages/get package to show dialogs/make navigation from your bloc, without notifying Page about the new state.

Personally I prefer 2, or 3.
But also sometimes use first one.

Comment: Would option 2 require my widget to be a stateful widget?

Comment: You need to set navigation key in MaterialApp (normally is a start point of the app), then you can write service for showing dialogs based on this key.

I'm just interesting, what is the problem to use Stateful widgets?

Comment: @MikeOttink you can check 3 option source code, to better understand solution 2.
3 is just a packaged solution of 2

Comment: Okay so in my App I have a material app nested inside the main material app. But this generates errors using Get. Any idea why and how I could solve them?

Comment: Okay got it working, damm that speed... The app is way faster now

Comment: Yo thanks for introducing met to Get, this is so much better than any other state management i've seen in flutter!

Comment: @MikeOttink Good to know! Have fun with flutter ;)